# How can I store a img into a MongoDB?

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, nodes, project

I need to make a "gallery" like Google Photos for a class project. My idea consists in a web app that allows a user to upload a file (image) and save it to a db and after that to show it in the web app.  I just want to know how should the **structure** of my collection be if that collection saves a file (<16MB I read for >16MB we have to use gridfs).

For the `back-end`, I will use Node (with Express, Mongoose ... and so on) and for the `front-end` I will use react or vue.js. I am not sure yet.

Any suggestion is accepted.

Comment: your question is too large & vague, you should probably investigate first...

Comment: I know store imgs into a db is not recomend. I just want to do the exercise. thanks

Comment: @VíctorVíctorRamosJiménez, if you are using Node/Express/Mongoose you will need to develop some schema models in which image will be one of the properties, but to further be of assistance, we would need to know more about this application. If its just uploading images to an app, you may want to use a different set of tools, otherwise you are facing a learning curve of putting together schemas, models and finding particular records in Mongo.

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following two things.

1. Upload image to s3 and save its link in the mongoDB. More Read(https://medium.com/@fabianopb/upload-files-with-node-and-react-to-aws-s3-in-3-steps-fdaa8581f2bd).
2. Save image in database in a GridFS collection. More Read
   (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/gridfs/#when-to-use-gridfs)

Comment: Thank, I read about GridFS but I think my photos are not going to weight >16MB. I appreciate your help.

Comment: why do you need to save file inside db?

Comment: convert image into base64 string and save it